# How do I add the random numbers I have filled a list with?

Tags: python, list

I am using a for loop to fill a list with 100 random numbers.  I want to add those numbers once the list is complete and I cannot figure out how to do that.  I am pretty sure it is something simple that I have just overlooked but it is driving me crazy that I can't get it to work.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Before asking questions, make sure that you've searched your question first.

Answer (score -1):

Use `sum(list)`

```py
list = [random.randint(1,9) for i in range(100)]
print(sum(list))
```

Comment: Better not to shadow built-in names -> `list`

Comment: just an example although it would still work

Comment: Yes it works but just not a good practice. Later lines may not work!. Just to mention I didn't downvote.

Comment: I need 50 rep to comment ;-;

Answer (score -1):

Python has a built in `sum` function

```
list_sum = sum(your_list)
```

Comment: Does this work if you are using a loop to fill the list?  I have tried this and it isn't working.

Comment: you do it outside of the loop after the loop is completed, not in. @1tgraham